# AES decryption error in java

Tags: java, aes

I am working on AES algorithm and I get this Exception:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
at org.enterprisepower.io.MyEncryptTools.decrypt(MyEncryptTools.java:41)
at org.enterprisepower.io.IOUtils.copyStream(IOUtils.java:132)
at org.enterprisepower.net.portforward.Processor$Copier.run(Processor.java:99)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

the exception happen in the decryption part.I encrypt a message in myClient program and send cipherMessage to myServer program.After server recieve the cipherMessage it throws the above exception, but in client I can decrypt the exact same cipherMessage.(I check this with printing the bytes in both side...)

These are my codes:

```
//It's decrypt method for both client and server
public  byte[] decrypt(byte[] encryptedData, int length) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] enc = new byte[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        enc[i] = encryptedData[i];
    }
    byte[] decordedValue= Base64.decodeBase64(enc);//org.apache.commons.codec.binary.*;
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    return decValue;
}


//Client side
public static void copyStream(InputStream in, OutputStream out,
        boolean closeOnFinish, boolean encrypt, String password) throws Exception {
    MyEncryptTools mit;
    try {
        mit = new MyEncryptTools(password);
        byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
        byte[] enbuf ;
        int count;
        try {
            if (encrypt) {
                while (((count = in.read(buf)) != -1) && alive) {
                    enbuf = mit.encrypt(buf,count);
                    out.write(enbuf, 0, enbuf.length);
                }
            } else {
                buf = new byte[172];
                while (((count = in.read(buf)) != -1) && alive) {
                    enbuf = mit.decrypt(buf, count);
                    out.write(enbuf, 0, enbuf.length);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (closeOnFinish)
                close(in);
            if (closeOnFinish)
                close(out);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}



//Server side
public static void copyStream(InputStream in, OutputStream out,
        boolean closeOnFinish, boolean encrypt, String user, String password) throws Exception {
    MyEncryptTools mit;
    try {
        mit = new MyEncryptTools(password);

        byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
        byte[] enbuf ;
        int count;
        try {
            if (encrypt) {
                System.out.println("Encrypt;");
                while (((count = in.read(buf)) != -1)) {
                    enbuf = mit.encrypt(buf,count);
                    out.write(enbuf, 0, enbuf.length);
                }
            } else {
                buf = new byte[172];
                while (((count = in.read(buf)) != -1)) {
                    enbuf = mit.decrypt(buf, count);
                    out.write(enbuf, 0, enbuf.length);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (closeOnFinish)
                close(in);
            if (closeOnFinish)
                close(out);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

I should mention that I use an array of 117 byte for encrypting and an array of 172 for decrypting.

Answer (score 2):

Use the wonderful CipherInputStream and forget about buffers length.

Comment: It seems great... how can I use it? Do you have any example code?

Comment: @M.S. just do 'CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(<yourInputStream>, <yourCipher>);' then read from the cis to an outputstream. See a few more examples here: 'http://www.google.com/codesearch#search&q=%22new%20CipherInputStream%22%20lang:^java$&type=cs'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I do this but it doesn't work well.After some lines, it stops. I use Cipher class with AES algorithm and a 16 character as key.Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: I want add something: after editing my program, it decrypt these lines:   GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3333
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.218 Safari/535.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q
but it stops at this point everytime and don't decrypt this characters:
=0.7,*;q=0.3                           
I don't know where is the problem...

Comment: I found that the problem is the end of file, that cipherInputStream don't understand it.

Comment: @M.S. You can make a small test using a simple byte array as plaintext to check if it is a problem related to the input file or the problem is in the way you call the CipherInputStream. But in my experience, it works quite well, and I'm using it to process large files.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message says: "Given final block not properly padded".  To fix the error specify PKCS7 padding for both encryption or decryption.  Alternatively switch to CTR mode, which does not require padding.